# Wrap the tree data item text in AG-Grid treeData

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am populating the tree using AG-Grid treeData. It displayed perfectly but my question is, are we able to wrap the tree data item text here?

I am Using `ag-grid-enterprise@19.0.0` library.

Comment: Hi, I think you will find that for questions like this, is best to add a plunker or any other reproducible scenario to illustrate your question, if you post it again with it, Ill try to answer it

Comment: Hi, I added the plunker link  "https://plnkr.co/edit/nTAfDLr16SCSTLBzRVM4?p=preview" for kendo tree view, here as, when click on "WrapText" the tree items text are wrapped and when click "nowrap" the tree items text is in single line.

Same functionality expect in ag-grid treeData https://plnkr.co/edit/CX2o5kROqM05am3zN2VP?p=preview

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the plunker provided in the comments, I think you are looking at row auto height..

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

This should work with tree data as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi Alberto,
Thanks for replay. I tried according to your above comment, like 
      autoGroupColumnDef: {
        headerName: 'Files',
        cellClass: 'cell-wrap-text',
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 250,
        cellRendererParams: {
            suppressCount: true,
            innerRenderer: 'fileCellRenderer'
        }
    }   in the gridOptions and even in ColumnDef also...

but its not working(item text is not wrap)

Comment: If you add a plunker of that, Ill have a look

Comment: hi, I achieved wrap text in Ag Grid tree data but the problem is row height is not 
automatically adjust according to text width. Here is the Plunker link for wrap text https://plnkr.co/edit/PoQnimd8TwG7pkli2CPf?p=preview
How can I solve this..?